# What is the Spinnaker pipeline expression for the current stage?

Tags: spring-el, spinnaker

I'm trying to write a Spinnaker pipeline expression that determines some criteria based on the current stage and its ancestors. Per the documentation, you can use [the `#root` helper](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/user/pipeline/expressions/#root) to get the current stage *context*; however, it doesn't appear there is any way to get the current *stage*.

For example, if you wanted to find out if the current stage has any ancestors that have a failure status, right now you have to know the stage name, which seems counter-intuitive given the existence of `#root`.

`${ #stage("My Stage").ancestors().?[status.isFailure() && name != "My Stage"] }`

**I'd like to replace the `#stage("My Stage")` with something *similar to* `#root`** however, again `#root` is the context object inside the stage, not the stage itself.

Note it also appears [the `Stage.ancestorsOnly()` method](https://github.com/spinnaker/orca/blob/master/orca-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/spinnaker/orca/pipeline/model/Stage.java#L372) is private at the moment so if you want to find *only ancestors* that have failed (or have some other criteria) you need to manually exclude the current stage. That's why I have the extra `name` comparison in there.

Answer (score 0):

## root and #this in SPEL are just aliases for when you need to reference the current object used in places like filters, I wouldn't get too caught up with it.

Maybe the right thing here is to add a few more values to the augmented context we evaluate SPEL against https://github.com/spinnaker/orca/blob/7de225679cf19cbcbfcfdbdcd08dc1962247f0fe/orca-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/spinnaker/orca/pipeline/util/ContextParameterProcessor.java#L90 to include values such as stage id so it would be easier to add helper functions like #currentStage() or #ancestorStaget() here https://github.com/spinnaker/orca/blob/fc87a8e99ec59a4e129646026987aa5adbde2d31/orca-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/spinnaker/orca/pipeline/expressions/ExpressionsSupport.java#L60

There are subtle issues here because stage expressions get evaluated before a stage runs so for static values like ancestors it should be ok, but for values like status the value you get will not be updated

Comment: `#root` is definitely an alias that works but `#this` doesn't appear to have any meaning in a Spinnaker pipeline expression. I tried `${ this }` and `${ #this }` with various attempts to read properties from them like `${ this.name }` and `${ #this.name }` with no luck.

Comment: Or is the answer, at this point, "There is no expression to access the current pipeline stage?"

Comment: you can only access the stage context, not anything else from an expression. If you wish to improve this you can submit a PR, we're happy to help you with it

Comment: I see. Your reference to `#this` was confusing, thanks for the clarification. If you update your answer to be slightly more clear (ie specifically calling out that you can only get the context and not the actual stage) I'd be happy to mark it as the answer and give you credit for it. Thanks for the help!